# Selenium script for dynamic ID textbox

Tags: ruby, selenium

I have to click on element whose Id is changeable,means dynamic value assign to text box everytime . I have to insert value in text box.
Following is the inspect element code of text box

```
    <div class="invoicing-details">
        <div>
        <label for="PaidToName_b62b89226e5f4fcbb74d0d27a9db88ca"> To </label>
        <input id="PaidToContactID" type="hidden" value="" name="PaidToContactID">
        <div class="controls">
        <input id="PaidToName_b62b89226e5f4fcbb74d0d27a9db88ca" type="hidden" style="display:none;" value="" name="PaidToName_b62b89226e5f4fcbb74d0d27a9db88ca">
        <input id="PaidToName_b62b89226e5f4fcbb74d0d27a9db88ca_value" class=" autocompleter field " type="text" style="width:127px;" tabindex="10" value="" maxlength="255" name="PaidToName_b62b89226e5f4fcbb74d0d27a9db88ca_value" autocomplete="off">
        <div id="PaidToName_b62b89226e5f4fcbb74d0d27a9db88ca_suggestions" class="autocomplete" style="display: none; height: 200px; width: 200px;"> </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
</div>
</div>
```

"PaidToName_b62b89226e5f4fcbb74d0d27a9db88ca_value" this is text box id.
I used following code
 self.set_text_value('div.invoicing-details input' ,"my value",true)
but it does not work and getting syntax error.
Can anyone help me and provide syntax how to write ruby script for seleinum.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic ids very bad for automation. You can try to add other property to input element with stable name. As i clearly understood you need to click on element and then input text in it?! I'm not good at ruby, but i think this should look like:

```
element = driver.find_elements(:css,".invoicing-details .autocompleter")
element.click
element.send_keys "Some text"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find id of an element using next xpath: `//input[@id=(//label[contains(text(),'To')]/@for)]`. Here you find a label by its text and then get `for` attribute (it is needed id).

```
element = driver.find_elements(:xpath,"//input[@id=(//label[contains(text(),'To')]/@for)]")
element.click
element.send_keys "Some text"
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate syntax properly.